# Codename One: TextArea / Textfield datachange listener with growing

Tags: user-interface, codenameone

I need a text field that grows vertically and I can attach data change and done listener to it. The [TextField](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/TextField.html) class has those, but does grows horizontally. The [TextArea](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/TextArea.html) class behaves as I want it, but I cannot attach done and data change listener to this component. What component should I use and how should I configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setSingleLineTextArea(false)` to flip the `TextField` behavior to `TextArea`.